# Shortcut for showing windows instead of clicking the Dock

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I use <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> to browse through my applications, and <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> for browsing through internal windows (e.g. for Firefox).

However, regularly, I switch to an application (e.g. TeXMaker and others) and only the menu bar shows up. They don't have a windows option, so I have to go all the way down to the Dock, find the application (which will have a dot on it) and click it. Then the windows will actually show.

I prefer not to use my mouse for this task. Is there any shortcut for this?

Comment: Try using CMD + N

Comment: @user3439894 Correct, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for some applications but not for all. You can use TextEdit.app to test it.

1. Open TextEdit.app
2. Create a new document (CMD+N).
3. Minimize the document (manually, CMD+M did not work for me).
4. CMD+Tab to Finder.app

Now everything's set up. The following steps may be a bit tricky.

1. **CMD+Tab** to highlight TextEdit. Keep the **CMD key pressed**.
2. Keep the CMD key pressed and **additionally press the Alt**/Opt key.
3. **Release the CMD** key.

This will un-minimize only the last window of a certain application. You cannot un-minimize multiple windows without additional scripts/software.

Comment: Oh this is excellent.Just tested it on chrome. You have to be sure to keep pressing Alt after you let go of cmd. Thanks!